# When I decorate a method that is called with only keyword arguments (and self) my IDE (PyCharm) complains that self is unfilled

Tags: python, pycharm, python-decorators, python-class

So I have a decorator that is something like this:

```py
def add_exclamation(method):
    def wrapper(self, *method_args, **method_kwargs):
        method_output = method(self, *method_args, **method_kwargs)
        return method_output + "!"

    return wrapper
```

Then I use it to decorate a method of my class that is only called with keyword arguments:

```py
class API(object):
    @add_exclamation
    def greet(self, word):
        return "Hello {}".format(word)

    def hello_world(self):
        return self.greet(word="World")
```

This works fine. so

```py
api = API()
print(api.hello_world())
```

prints "Hello World!" as expected

Unfortunately my IDE (PyCharm) complains that my call self.greet(word="World") is missing a required positional parameter "self". This is presumably because it doesn't recognise the function wrapper as being bound to an IDE instance, so it think self is just any old parameter. Since it works at runtime, I could just leave it, but that little yellow warning is irritating me

Is there something that I can do to tell PyCharm/linters, that the self parameter is wrapper is not expected to be in the call.

Comment: Is there a reason your passing `self` in the wrapper. Just remove those reference and pass the args and kwargs

Answer (score 0):

self is just a method_arg ... so just use that ...

```
def add_exclamation(method):
    def wrapper(*method_args, **method_kwargs):
        method_output = method(*method_args, **method_kwargs)
        if isinstance(method_output,str): # be safe
            return method_output + "!"
        return method_output
    return wrapper

class API(object):
    @add_exclamation # by using the * now it only accepts kwargs
    def greet(self, *, word):
        return "Hello {}".format(word)
    
a = API()
print(a.greet(word="asd"))
```

that said i dont get any  warnings if i do explicitly call out `self` in the wrapper either... I just dont understand why you would